# applying an elementwise rule while performing a numpy broadcasting operation

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I want to multiply two numeric numpy objects `t` and `speed` without knowing a-priori whether each one is scalar or an array.  The problem is that 0 is a legal value for `t` (or for elements of `t`),  and `inf` is a legal value for `speed` (or for elements of `speed`).  The model I'm working with has a rule for this case:  wherever speed is infinite and `t` is zero, the product is defined as 0.

My problem is in applying the rule while coping with the possibly-scalar-possibly-not-ness of both operands. So far the best I can come up with is this ugly cascade:

```
if t.size == 1:
    if t.flat[0]:
        t = t * speed
else:
    nonzero = t != 0
    if speed.size == 1:
        t[nonzero] *= speed
    else:
        t[nonzero] *= speed[nonzero]
```

I can't help but think there has to be a more efficient, more Numpythonic way that I'm missing.  Is there?

Comment: If you really wanted to, you could throw the your "if t.size==1" and corresponding "else" conditional (the outer clauses) into a list comprehension and then go so far as to throw your sub-conditional (the speed.size case) into another list comprehension. The thing I would suggest is to use numpy operations and broadcasting. Use functions such as [np.where] (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and utilize the fact that numpy allows you to broadcast your vector operations and other weird things.

Comment: @SachinRaghavendran Thanks, but the question already begins from the position of knowing about broadcasting.  In the listing, note that the three multiplication operations at the leaves of the logic tree *are* already (potentially) broadcasting operations.  The question is how to apply the specific `0*inf`  handling rule *while* doing that.

Comment: `ufunc` like multiple take a `where` parameter.  Use it with an `out` parameter

Comment: @hpaulj  This is the answer I was looking for—a more general approach leveraging broadcasting features that I hadn't encountered before, in contrast to warped's answer below which works perfectly well but only for the *particular* rule in this example. Would you care to make it into an actual answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I'm using a phone so can't write a proper answer.

Comment: @hpaulj Understood. Here's the comment I would write if you did:  What's the efficient way of generating an `out=` argument value of the appropriate size?  My hacky way is `numpy.multiply(t, speed, where=t!=0, out=numpy.zeros_like(t+speed))` but obviously doing the broadcast operation `t+speed` just to get the right (broadcasted) shape is neither readable nor efficient.

Comment: would `np.zeros(np.broadcast(t, speed).shape)` be better? It's less readable, but maybe more efficient?

Comment: @SubhaneilLahiri  Thank you, I think that's the right answer.  Although it's more characters, I would argue it is *more* readable because it's used explicitly for its correct purpose (by contrast, the maintainer's initial reaction to my hack might easily be "Why are we adding time plus speed here? That doesn't make sense.")  It lacks the `dtype` (which it's disappointing that `broadcast()` doesn't provide) but I guess that's easily added in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a couple of days, and nobody has written up the answer given in comments by hpaulj and SubhaneilLahiri, so I had better do it myself. My reason for making this the accepted answer is that it is general enough to address the question's title, even in cases that go beyond the specific model given in the question.

```
# prepare zeros of the correct shape:
out = np.zeros(np.broadcast(t, speed).shape), dtype=float)

# write the product values into the prepared array, but ONLY
# according to the mask t!=0 
np.multiply(t, speed, where=t!=0, out=out)
```

In the particular model in the question, the pre-prepared default output value of 0 is already correct for all places where the test `t!=0` fails: `0 * speed` is `0` anyway wherever `speed` is finite, and it is also `0` by fiat (according to the model's rule) when `speed` is infinite.  But this approach is adaptable to the more general case: in principle, it would be possible to use additional numpy ufunc calls to fill in the masked-out parts of the output array with the results of arbitrarily different rules.

Answer (score 1):

`0 * np.inf` throws a `RuntimeWarning` and evaluates to `np.nan` 
How about just doing the multiplication, and replacing the `np.nan` after that?

```
import numpy as np

def multiply(a, b):
    temp = np.array(a*b)
    temp[np.isnan(temp)] = 0
    return temp
```

Testing:

```
np.random.seed(123)
t = np.random.rand(10)
t[0] = 0
speed = np.random.rand(10)
speed[0] = np.inf
speed[6] = np.inf
```

input:

```
multiply(t, speed)
```

output:

```
array([ 0.        ,  0.09201602,  0.02440781,  0.49796297,  0.06170694,
    0.57372377,         inf,  0.03658583,  0.53141369,  0.1746193 ])
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks, yes, I think this would work for my case. A further improvement would be to do it inside a `with numpy.errstate(invalid='ignore'):` clause to suppress the warning.

Comment: You also have to say `temp=numpy.array(a*b)` rather than `temp=a*b` because the subsequent line, which uses indexing, won't otherwise work in the scalar case.